# GLEW and GLFW .dylib files missing MAC

Tags: c++, glfw, glew

For some reason when I install GLEW and GLFW the lib folders are empty. I can't locate the .dylib files anywhere. Anyone have any ideas? Using a Mac running Sierra.

Comment: how are you doing the install ... are you getting the header files

Comment: an opengl function loader is not needed on mac (GLEW).

Comment: yea im getting header files in both but no .dylib files. Just downloading from their websites.

Answer (score 1):

glfw still needs to be compiled for your mac. The ReadMe file in the download folder will direct you to this link

http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/compile.html#compile_deps_xcode

for directions on compiling glfw. 
An alternative an easy way to get glfw installed on your system is to use homebrew. If you don't already have homebrew you can install it in terminal with the command

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

Then glfw can be installed by the terminal command

brew install glfw3

The .dylib files will then likely be located in the directories
/usr/local/Cellar/glfw and
/usr/local/lib

Comment: Thank you, I had messed up my paths so couldn't use homebrew but now it's all fixed and working!